# Imagemagick path for codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, imagemagick, image-manipulation, imagemagick-convert

I am using Imagemagick library for applying effects on images. I am using it with codeigniter, on wamp on windows 7. I am facing issue of "Image processing failed. Please verify that your server supports the chosen protocol and that the path to your image library is correct". Can anyone help to resolve this issue? What path should i pass in "$config['library_path']" for wamp on windows 7?
TIA guys

Comment: Perhaps codeigniter expect you to have ImageMagick 6 rather than ImageMagick 7? What version of ImageMagick do you actually have? Have you provided codeigniter with the path to ImageMagick convert/magick? See Preference at https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html in order to configure codeigniter with the path to ImageMagick. Sorry, I have not used code igniter and have little knowledge about it other than the page I referenced. Just suggesting some logical things to check.

Comment: Currently i am using imagemagick 7. LEt me try with version 6.

Comment: @fmw42 i tried with version 6 but no success. You have any other idea?

Comment: No sorry, no more ideas, since I know nothing about codeigniter, or wamp or windows 7

Comment: @fmw42 Ok, Thanks for your time. I will try to find out some other way